# Do you say "despite living in the US for more than 15 yrs"?

Tags: present-perfect

Here is the complete sentence:

> Numerous collections of short stories include works by Isaac Bashevis Singer who, **despite living in the US for more than 15 years**, continued to write primarily in Yiddish.

If it were just **despite living in the US**, it would all just be fine. But the years indicate that he has been living there for sometimes. So I feel that **despite having lived in the US for more than 15 yrs** would be more correct.

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Despite *having lived* in the US for more than fifteen years” is indeed perfectly good English but it would imply that the 15+-year period of US residency *preceded* the writing in question. Your source has made a valid choice to indicate that, on the contrary, the two were simultaneous. And that original version is also perfectly good English. So your supposed correction is uncalled-for.

Comment: Note that the past tense of _continued_ combined with the present gerund _living_ fairly unambiguously means that Singer is no longer alive. If we expand the whole thing to finite forms and include some clarifications here and there, it’s saying, “Singer, who continued throughout his life to write primarily in Yiddish, even though he lived in the US for more than 15 years”.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by "simultaneously".

Comment: @user132522, Singer was writing in Yiddish *during* his fifteen plus years living in the US, and not (just) *afterwards.* Is that clearer? (Actually I did not use the adverb *simultaneously,* nor did any one else.)